# Javascript jquery - How do I build a delay into the search entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax search box that goes to the server on every key stroke and returns the result of the search. 
When the user types quickly, I want to search only on the last entry and not on every key stroke. Otherwise the individual results flash annoyingly and the whole process is slowed.

For example: if the user types "statue of liberty" quickly, I don't want to search on "sta", "stat", "statu" etc.

the basics of my jQuery code is:

```
$('#searchbox').keyup(function(){
    if (this.value.length > 2) {    
        $.post("remote.php",{'partial':this.value},function(data){
            $("#gen_results").html(data);
        });
    }
});        


<input id="searchbox" />
<div id="gen_results"></div>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

use setTimeout or jQuery's [autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete)

```
var timer;
$('#searchbox').keyup(function(){
    if (this.value.length > 2) {
        if (timer){
                clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
                $.post("remote.php",{'partial':this.value},function(data){
                $("#gen_results").html(data);
                });
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Make sure you cancel the previous timer.

Comment: thanks, this works nicely. The only glitch is that this.value doesn't reflect the search box anymore. So after the keyup function() { I added: var token = this.value; and in the post I use {'partial': token}

Comment: +1! for some reason beyond my skillset, `$(this).val()` wasn't working but `this.value` was for me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a timeout, this one is set to 500ms, but you might want to go quicker.

```
$('#searchbox').keyup(function(){
  window.clearTimeout(window.timeOutId);
  window.timeOutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
    if (this.value.length > 2) {    
      $.post("remote.php",{'partial':this.value},function(data){
       $("#gen_results").html(data);
      });
    }
  },500); 
});
```

Hope that works for you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var inProgress = false;
$('#searchbox').keyup(function(){
    if (this.value.length > 2 && !inProgress) {    
        inProgress  = true;
        $.post("remote.php",{'partial':this.value},function(data){
            $("#gen_results").html(data);
            inProgress = false;
        });
    }
});
```

This way you dont have to maintain a timer, just another call if the previous call is complete and by that time user has typed something more.

Comment: Won't this miss and never execute a search on the last keystroke if we're in middle of a search?

Comment: If the previous post is successful and by the time the last keystroke is fired it will make a new call.

Comment: yes, but what happens if it's still in middle of the search when the last keystroke is entered?

Answer (score 1):

```
function getResults(value) {
   return function() {
       $.post("remote.php",{'partial':value},function(data){
           $("#gen_results").html(data);
       });
   };
}

var timerId;
$('#searchbox').keyup(function(){
    if (this.value.length > 2) {
          clearTimeout(timerId);
          timerId = setTimout(getResults(this.value), 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar once. What I did was set a timer each 500ms, and when the timer is called it does the AJAX request. The trick is that whenever the user typed something, I would reset the timer.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a global variable holding the timestamp of the last keystroke.  When the keyup method is called, take a timestamp reading and compare it to the previous value.  If it is over a certain time frame, make your call, otherwise, reset the global value and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building this yourself have a look at the [jQuery Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) plugin.

Using this you can [set a delay option](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#option-delay) so that requests wait for a given period after a keystroke.

> The delay in milliseconds the Autocomplete waits after a keystroke to
>   activate itself. A zero-delay makes sense for local data (more
>   responsive), but can produce a lot of load for remote data, while
>   being less responsive.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. I use autoComplete often, however in this instance I need to return formatted results with html and <a> tags which autoComplete does not allow. I have wrestled with that alot.